# Converting coordinates to Google Maps

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, coordinates, geocoding, wgs84

I want to find where the following coordinates fall on Google Maps.

I know Google Maps works in WGS 84 Standard, however, I can't figure out in what standard this coordinates works. Been helplessly looking the internet but I can't find a reliable source:

```
<EPSGCode>32636</EPSGCode>
<Eastings>750400</Eastings>
<Northings>3000500</Northings>
```

Any idea how to convert those to WGS 84? Thanks

Comment: You can find out more information [here](https://epsg.io/32636). It's quite a small area of the earth that it covers. The values you have are in metres from a starting location. From a conversion perspective I honestly don't know.

Answer (score 0):

Global Coordinate Converter by Reality GIS can be found [Here](http://www.realitygeo.com/coordinates.aspx)

```
<EPSGCode>32636</EPSGCode>
<Eastings>750400</Eastings>
<Northings>3000500</Northings>
```

gives latitude  27.1042722 and logitude 35.5256594